# How to install SSL certificate in Azure purchased from GoDaddy

Tags: azure, ssl, iis, openssl, ssl-certificate

I've purchased SSL certificate for my website from GoDaddy, I've got two crt files and one pem file. But in Azure it is expecting pfx file, I've tried conversion methods referred in godaddy site, and it's mentioning about p7b files, which I don't have. openssl also tried and it is expecting a private key file.

What is the steps to convert crt and pem file to pfx file and how can I get p7b file?

Comment: Have you read the instructions here: https://in.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-microsoft-azure-web-app-32071.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the official [GoDdady](https://in.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-microsoft-azure-web-app-32071) and [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate?tabs=apex#private-certificate-requirements) documentation to install a third-party SSL certificate on Azure.

To convert a PEM file to PKCS#7 (the .p7b file does not include the private key) use the following OpenSSL command:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile certificatename.pem -out certificatename.p7b -certfile CACert.cer
```

To Convert PKCS7 (.p7b) to PKCS12 (.pfx) you’ll first convert the P7B file to CER and then combine CER and Private Key into PFX.

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificatename.p7b -out certificatename.cer

openssl pkcs12 -export -in certificatename.cer -inkey privateKey.key -out certificatename.pfx -certfile  cacert.cer
```

Alternatively, you can google and use an online SSL converter tool.

Comment: how can i generate the privatekey.key file?

Comment: The private key is created when you generate the CSR (Certificate Signing Request) on your server or via a CSR generator tool. Where did you generate the CSR? If you can't find the private key, you have the option to rekey your certificate. https://in.godaddy.com/help/rekey-my-certificate-4976